# Batch script to list the files above a specified size inside a folder ordered by Size

Tags: batch-file

I have this code to list the files above a particular size inside a folder? 
But I want the list to be in sorted order by "Size"

Could anyone please help me with this?

```
@echo off & setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd D:\temp_files

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir/b/s') do (

if %%~Za gtr 1000000 echo %%~nxa%tab% %%~Za%tab% %%~ta >>test_list.txt

)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you type `help dir` or `dir /?` from the command line you will see that the DIR command has the `/O-S` option that allows you to sort the output by size descending. Also, you probably want `/A-D` to eliminate directories from the output.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /b /s /o-s /a-d') do (
```